# Two parallel capacitors in natural response of RC circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, time-constant

I found U(0) to be 3.6 V but, when writing u<sub>x</sub>(t), I found the time constant to be 0.3 s (5 x 0.060).

I think there is something wrong here. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: How did you arrive at τ = 3.33s?

Comment: @vir 5*60*(10^-3). time constant is 0.3s, I I typed it wrong.

Comment: it's 0.4 seconds.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit new information like this into your question rather than post it in comments. Otherwise, readers have to piece together the full question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your circuit, τ = RC. The 20 Ω resistor doesn't participate since it's disconnected by the switch. The 60 mF and 20 mF capacitors are in parallel, so they add to 80 mF. 80 mF * 5 Ω = 400 ms.

Comment: Do the two capacitors have to have a common time constant?

Comment: Yes, because they are connected in parallel.

Comment: I understand. In this case, it becomes Ux(t)=3.6 * e^(-2,5t).

Comment: thank you very much